# Facebook Login error

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-ios-sdk

Application required login through Facebook account.If Facebook account not configured in phone it work fine and login into application successfully but when Facebook account is configured and try login into the App it will give me an error

```
Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 2.)" UserInfo=0x9dce820 {com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedReason=com.facebook.sdk:SystemLoginDisallowedWithoutError, com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey=<FBSession: 0x9dab260, state: FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed, loginHandler: 0x0, appID: 326324637530004, urlSchemeSuffix: , tokenCachingStrategy:<FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy: 0xa9cc040>, expirationDate: (null), refreshDate: (null), attemptedRefreshDate: 0001-12-30 00:00:00 +0000, permissions:(null)>}
```

see my source code

```
AppDelegate.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) FBSession *session;
@end

AppDelegate.m

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>

@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize session = _session;
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [FBProfilePictureView class];
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation
{
    return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
}


Login.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>

@interface Login : UIViewController<FBLoginViewDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) id<FBGraphUser> loggedInUser;
@end

Login.m

#import "Login.h"
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>

@interface Login ()
{
    FBLoginView *loginview;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *FB_login;

@end

@implementation Login

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    loginview = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];
    loginview = [[FBLoginView alloc] initWithReadPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email",@"public_profile",nil]];
    loginview.frame =CGRectMake(10,100, 280, 55);
loginview.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:loginview];
}

- (void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView {

    NSLog(@"Logged In");
}

- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                            user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {
    NSLog(@"User info ");
}

- (void)loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView {
    NSLog(@"Logged out");
    [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
}

- (void)loginView:(FBLoginView *)loginView handleError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"FBLoginView encountered an error=%@", error);
}
```

Comment: Are you doing it through `Social` framework? Or using separate `facebook SDK`

Comment: using with facebook sdk

Comment: first of all add the user_friends permission to the permission array
    loginview = [[FBLoginView alloc] initWithReadPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email",@"public_profile",@"user_friends",nil]]

Comment: @BogdanSomlea still same error after adding user_friends.. :( :(.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to set your permissions initially to 'email', "The proxied app cannot request publish permissions without having being installed previously."

```
loginview.readPermissions = @[@"email"];
```

Also make sure your production app is set up correctly in developers.facebook.com

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/#prerequisites